# c# path to file change after using mapimailmessage

Tags: c#

There is a strange behaviour that i dont understand.

There'the part of the code wich is imply in my problem.

```
public static NpgsqlConnection ConnectRead()
    {
        string pass = "password_here";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Stc.cts");
        string line;
        string conn = "";

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            conn = line;
        }
        sr.Close();

        conn = Cdf.Cdf.Crypt.Decrypt(conn, pass);

        NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(conn);

        con.Open();

        return con;

    }
```

and

```
if (mailCheckBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    string subject = pototal;
                    string body = "Voici le bon de commande";

                    MapiMailMessage message = new MapiMailMessage(subject, body);
                    //message.Files.Add(serveur + nomfichier);
                    message.Files.Add(@"c:\pdftemp\" + nomfichier);


                    message.ShowDialog();
                }
```

As you can see, the first part is a connection string and the second one is a mapi to open default mail software.

My problem is: If i dont use the mapi portion of my program, everything work perfectly. If i use the mapi portion, my program stop connecting because it seems to change the Stc.cts path to c:/foxmail/Stc.cts.

If anyone have a clue, i would realy appreciate.

Comment: Your file is relative (`@"Stc.cts"`), and that path can change based on anything setting the "current (working) directory". You should provide the full absolute path so that it's independent of assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though your code is using a relative path. You should provide an absolute path in case something changes the "current" directory.

For example, if your file is in the same path as your executable, you could do this:

```
string strAppDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
// or...
// string strAppDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string strFullPathToMyFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(strAppDir, "Stc.cts");
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFullPathToMyFile);
```